# Remove content from XML node with sed

Tags: regex, xml, linux, sed, xml-parsing

My XML input file looks like this:

```
...
  <logos>
    <logo name="" primary="true" guid="c6aae8fe-bb04-4067-9b14-18b1bcf940d3" />
    <logo name="" primary="false" guid="68b55f4d-f401-4180-b0e0-160974758348" />

  </logos>
...
```

I need to remove the *content*, keeping the *node*. Expected output:

`<logos></logos>`

My command looks like this:

```
sed -i 's|\(<logos>\)\(.+\)\(</logos>\)|\1\3|gi' $filename
```

But it ain't working. What am I missing?

**Edit**: this is not a duplicate of [delete node in a xml file with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824010/delete-node-in-a-xml-file-with-sed) : that question is about deleting the *whole node*. Here I need to delete *the content of the node only*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete node in a xml file with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40824010/608639), [Using sed to delete node and data from XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21726814/608639), etc. Also see [sed delete xml tag site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=sed+delete+xml+tag+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @jww Saw that, thanks, but it's about deleting the whole node, not just the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use address ranges in addition to `c` command:

```
sed -i.bak '/<logos>/,/<\/logos>/c<logos></logos>' $filename
```

Answer (score -1):

`sed` and alike would be a bad choice for such cases.
Use a proper XML/HTML parsers.

**`xmlstarlet`** solution:

Sample `input.xml`:

```
<root>
<logos>
    <logo name="" primary="true" guid="c6aae8fe-bb04-4067-9b14-18b1bcf940d3"/>
    <logo name="" primary="false" guid="68b55f4d-f401-4180-b0e0-160974758348"/>
  </logos>
</root>
```

---

```
xmlstarlet ed -O -d '//logos/*' input.xml
```

The output:

```
<root>
  <logos/>
</root>
```